# ajax code for enabling and disabling dropdown box

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to write an ajax function to disable a dropdown, until its parent dropdown is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using the 'AJAX Control Toolkit', it sounds like you want to use [the Cascading Drop Down](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)